# Sklearn Random Forest Classifier feature analysis at each tree level

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have an Random Forest Classifier with a tree depth of 14 and 120 estimators.

```
rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier(  
             n_estimators=120,
             criterion='gini',
             max_features= None, 
             max_depth = 14 )

rnd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How can I create a table which analysis all 300 features (most discriminate feature, etc.) at each tree level?

Example:

[image]

Simply put I am looking for the feature importance of each feature at each tree level.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you please elaborate what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, for example you can use rnd_clf.feature_importances_ this gets you the global feature ranking. What I would like to know is the contribution / importance of each feature at each tree level and get in a table form.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: If I understand you correctly, why not loop `max_depth=1, 2, ...`? I think you might be able to get away with a single `fit` and looping `max_depth` after, but I'm not sure without spending more time [looking at the way feature importances are computed](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4c61e8b2237a5877b47b22cbb5037430c5635e74/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L1056).

Comment: Do you mean to say you want details of weak learners which random forest aggregates and form strong learner?

Comment: @AyushKesarwani I want to find the most discriminate features at root until my maximum tree depth.

Comment: In my knowledge using sklearn random forest, you can't get this. What you can do is train Decision tree classifier and then get the table in the format you are looking for.

Comment: What I can do is set `DicisionTreeClassifier = rnd_clf.estimators_` and then access each decision tree by iterating through the list `DicisionTreeClassifier[n_estimators]`. How can you create a table for DicisionTreeClassifier? Maybe we can iterate over it later.