# Not Fitted Error when using Sklearn's graphviz

Tags: scikit-learn

when I am trying to export a random forest graph using the following command:

```
tree.export_graphviz(rnd_clf, out_file = None, feature_names = X_test[::1])
```

I receive the following error:

```
NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. 
Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

What I don't understand is why it keeps telling me this, even though I have fitted the random forest classifier using:

```
rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier(  
             n_estimators=120,
             criterion='gini',
             max_features= None, 
             max_depth = 14 )

rnd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(Only going by the docs; no personal experience)

You are trying to plot some **DecisionTree**, using a function which signature reads:

```
sklearn.tree.export_graphviz(decision_tree, ...)
```

but you are passing a **RandomForest**, which is an **ensemble of trees**.

That's not going to work!

Going deeper, the code internally for this is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/tree/export.py#L392):

```
check_is_fitted(decision_tree, 'tree_')
```

So this is asking for the attribute `tree_` of your DecisionTree, which exists for a [DecisionTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier).

This attribute does not exist for a [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)! Therefore the error.

The only thing you can do: print every DecisionTree within your RandomForest ensemble. For this, you need to traverse `random_forest.estimators_` to get the underlying decision-trees!

Comment: Thank you! I just thought that export_graphviz(decision_tree, ...) would be capable of display a full random forest. A quick followup question, displaying more than 100 trees in my case poses a visualisation problem.  
Is it possible to create a table which displays the most discriminate features at each tree depth?
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161849/sklearn-random-forest-classifier-feature-analysis-at-each-tree-level)

Comment: That's not my area of expertise. Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

Like the other answer said, you cannot do this for a forest, only a single tree. You can, however, graph a single tree from that forest. Here's how to do that:

```
forest_clf = RandomForestClassifier()
forest_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
tree.export_graphviz(forest_clf.estimators_[0], out_file='tree_from_forest.dot')
(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('tree_from_forest.dot')
graph.write_png('tree_from_forest.png')
```

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to graph the "best" tree or an overall ensemble tree from your forest, just a random example tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code herefrom IPython.display import Image
from sklearn.`enter code here`externals.six import StringIO
from sklear`enter code here`n.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
import pydot`enter code here`

    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', max_depth = 3, min_samples_split = 20, class_weight = "balanced")
    dtree = dt.fit(ctg_x_train,ctg_y_train)
    
        k
    
    dot_data = StringIO()
    ctg_x_train_names = ctg_x_train.columns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
    
    export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=dot_data,filled = True, rounded = True,special_characters = True, feature_names = ctg_x_train_names)
    
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
    
    (graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
    Image(graph.create_png())
```